# Block per block file copying

Tags: objective-c, file-copying

Is there a good way to copy some file or directory(with files and subdirectories) block per block in Mac OS with objective c?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to copy it blockwise? And what operating system are we talking about? MacOS? iOS? Something else?

Comment: What do you means with "block per block"?

Comment: Sorry. We talking about MacOS. I need an ability to pause copy process, then after each next block I will able to check flag and then pause or resume(if it paused) process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a file per blocks by creating a `NSInputStream` and a `NSOutputStream` and scheduling them in a `NSRunLoop`. Then, when you get bytes from the input stream, you write them in a buffer and when the output stream is ready, you copy the contents of the buffer into it.

```
@synthesize numberOfBytesTransferred = _numberOfBytesTransferred;

static const NSUInteger blockSize = 65536; // should be adjusted

- (void)startWithSourcePath:(NSString *)srcPath
            destinationPath:(NSString *)dstPath
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSUInteger, NSError *))completionHandler
{
    _buffer = malloc(blockSize);
    _numberOfBytesTransferred = _bufferLength = _bufferOffset = 0;
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
    _srcStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:srcPath];
    _dstStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:dstPath append:NO];
    _srcStream.delegate = self;
    _dstStream.delegate = self;
    [_srcStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [_dstStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [_srcStream open];
    [_dstStream open];
}

- (void)processStreams
{    
    if ( _srcStream.hasBytesAvailable && ! _bufferLength )
        _bufferLength = [_srcStream read:_buffer maxLength:blockSize];

    if ( _dstStream.hasSpaceAvailable && _bufferLength ) {
        NSInteger length = [_dstStream write:_buffer + _bufferOffset maxLength:_bufferLength];
        _bufferOffset += length;
        _bufferLength -= length;
    }

    if ( _bufferOffset && !_bufferLength ) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"numberOfBytesTransferred"];
        _numberOfBytesTransferred += _bufferOffset;
        _bufferOffset = 0;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"numberOfBytesTransferred"];
    }

    if ( _dstStream.hasSpaceAvailable && NSStreamStatusAtEnd == _srcStream.streamStatus ) {
        [_srcStream close];
        [_dstStream close];
        _completionHandler(_numberOfBytesTransferred, nil);
    }
}

- (void)cancel
{
    [_srcStream close];
    [_dstStream close];
}

- (void)pause
{
    _paused = YES;
}

- (void)resume
{
    _paused = NO;
    [self processStreams];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    if ( NSStreamEventErrorOccurred == eventCode ) {
        [_srcStream close];
        [_dstStream close];
        _completionHandler(_numberOfBytesTransferred, stream.streamError);
        return;
    }

    if ( ! _paused )
        [self processStreams];
}
```

Copying the contents of a directory will require to enumerate through the contents of the directory. You can create an instance of `NSDirectoryEnumerator` with `-[NSFileManager enumeratorAtPath:]`.

Once you have the enumerator, you call `nextObject` then get the file attributes:

- If the file is a directory, you create a new directory in the destination directory
- If the file is a regular file, you start a file copy task and wait until the completion handler is called.

Comment: Thanks, but i have two questions. Is that a really good idea to copy files per blocks? If i copy file with this way and with for example FSCopyObjectAsync, what about copy speed?

Comment: I think using a `FSFileOperation` can be more efficient. The operation will be preflighted so it will take longer to start. But it also possibly uses some optimizations that increase I/O performance like mapping the file into memory.

Comment: if you want to copy by block, do not forget, resources forks, rights, metadata, ....

Comment: AP - what additional metadata, rights, etc might you suggest that one should transfer from the original file to the copy?  For example, NSURLContentModificationDateKey, NSURLCreationDateKey are no brainers.  What about NSURLFileSecurityKey?  others?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a file or directory with `-[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]`.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *srcPath = @"/Users/nicolas/Documents/Xcode projects";
NSString *dstPath = @"/Users/nicolas/Desktop/Backup/Xcode projects";
NSError *error;
if ( ! [fileManager copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error] )
    NSLog(@"Copy error: %@", error);
```

Comment: Yes, I did but I misunderstood it. I'm completely ashamed of this answer.

Comment: I think it's my mistake in bad question structure and my bad English =)